# Yii how to retrieve a row, delete and insert a new row in another table

Tags: php, yii

How do you retrieve a row, delete and insert a new row in another table with Yii framework? Below is what I have so far...

```
$users=Entrepreneur_temp::model()->find('email=?', array($email));
            $model->setAttributes($users);

            if(isset($users)){

            $model=new Entrepreneur;
            $model->attributes = $users;

            if($model->save()){
            echo "true";
            }else{
                echo "error a";
            }

            }else{
                echo "error";
            }
```

Comment: I would suggest you look at this section: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.overview it's quite good at explaining the various ways of interacting with databases in Yii.

Comment: what do you mean by "another table"? why are you loading a list of users into a single entrepreneur model? twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing something that's ideal, but to answer your question:

In your AR class, add a member called $tableName, then override tableName(), to return your new varialbe. You can then do something like:

```
$user = User::model()->findByPk(1);
$user->tableName = 'other_table';
$user->save();
```

(a setter for table name would be better)

I have not tested this, but I can't see any reason why it would not work.